# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to access a table from PostgreSQL present in other machine.
I am getting the following error.

```
Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the
postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.<init>(Jdbc3Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I have configured my ip in pg_hba.conf file as well but the same error exists. What could be the solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

Can you telnet to the IP address and port number where you think PostgreSQL is listening?

- If not, the trouble is that the postmaster is not running, or that you have something screwball in your network - firewalls blocking access to the port, or can't locate the host or whatever.
- If you can get to the postmaster via telnet, then it may be that you've given the wrong credentials or something - but the error suggests that your client code is unable to find the remote PostgreSQL.  More likely, though, the configuration being used by the Java code is not the same as the one you successfully demonstrated as working with telnet.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to PostgreSql but i also had a same problem so many times, at last i found solution.

The problem was with firewall blocking port (for Ex : 5432) , once this was granted access through the firewall, i was able to connect to the database server.

You have to add only port which you are using in postgreSql to Firewall.

after this my postgreSql works Fine with Jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

What is the setting for "listen_addresses" in postgresql.conf?

```
SHOW listen_addresses;
```

And did you reload the configurationfiles after the changes in pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf?

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Comment: Could you show us pg_hba.conf ? The error must be in this file when the listen_addresses allows connections from all addresses. Or you didn't reload pg_hba.conf after the changes made.

Comment: i get the following o/p on executing the select pg reload...  pg_reload_conf
----------------
 t
(1 row)

Comment: # TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
host all     all  172.16.x.x/32  md5
host    all         all         172.16.y.y/32        md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5  where x is the machine where pg is running and y is my ip..i  cant display the x and y

Comment: Just to test, could you change "md5" into "trust" and reload the file? Does this work?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're looking at the right pg_hba.conf? Check SHOW hba_file;

Comment: ya iam 100% sure. also i think the problem is that since the server is running on win7 and mine is xp, my machine is unable to access the service running on win7..

Comment: FYI, if your listen_addresses line starts with a # it's commented out and won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I has same problem. I added following entry in pg_hba.conf and worked. Make sure you restart postgres after changin configuration file

```
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0         md5
```